# Airflow cannot communicate with my spark master to launch a pyspark job

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, airflow, airflow-2.x

My environment is as follows:

- standalone execution of spark (1 master and 1 worker)
- an airflow run on docker desktop (built with the docker-compose available with the curl command curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.3/docker-compose.yaml'
- image built from apache/airflow:2.6.3 and customized :

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.6.3

USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y procps && \
    apt-get clean;

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

USER airflow
```

Spark config :

- Spark UI : http://localhost:8080/
- URL: spark://MacBook-Pro-de-Admin-9.local:7077
- Alive Workers: 1
- Cores in use: 8 Total, 0 Used
- Memory in use: 7.0 GiB Total, 0.0 B Used
- Resources in use:
- Applications: 0 Running, 0 Completed
- Drivers: 0 Running, 0 Completed
- Status: ALIVE

Airflow config :

- Airflow UI : http://localhost:8082/
- provider added in docker-compose.yaml : apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark
- spark connection conf :

```
       Connection Id : spark_connection
       Connection Type : Spark
       Host : spark://MacBook-Pro-de-Admin-9.local
       Port : 7077
       Extra : {}
```

My airflow application contains 2 files (a pyspark script to be called by the DAG script + the DAG script)

here's the python script sparkjob.py :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("test") \
    .getOrCreate()

data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
```

here is the DAG script dag-airflow-spark-submitop.py :

```
import airflow
import pendulum
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import SparkSubmitOperator
from airflow import DAG, Dataset
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

with DAG(
    dag_id="my_test_dag",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 8, 7),
) as dag1:
    SparkSubmitOperator(task_id='task_spark_test', conn_id='spark_connection', application="/opt/airflow/dags/sparkjob.py")
```

Here is the Graph view of my dag before it started and once it was finished:
[image: Graph view before]
[image: Graph view after]

You can see that the task has failed. And here are the task logs available in Airflow :

```
*** Found local files:
***   * /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=my_test_dag/run_id=manual__2023-08-08T13:59:24.995099+00:00/task_id=task_spark_test/attempt=1.log
[2023-08-08, 13:59:27 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: my_test_dag.task_spark_test manual__2023-08-08T13:59:24.995099+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-08-08, 13:59:27 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: my_test_dag.task_spark_test manual__2023-08-08T13:59:24.995099+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-08-08, 13:59:27 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1308} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2023-08-08, 13:59:27 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1327} INFO - Executing <Task(SparkSubmitOperator): task_spark_test> on 2023-08-08 13:59:24.995099+00:00
[2023-08-08, 13:59:27 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:57} INFO - Started process 1643 to run task
[2023-08-08, 13:59:27 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:84} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'my_test_dag', 'task_spark_test', 'manual__2023-08-08T13:59:24.995099+00:00', '--job-id', '393', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dag-***-spark-submitop.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpwku9qcic']
[2023-08-08, 13:59:27 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:85} INFO - Job 393: Subtask task_spark_test
[2023-08-08, 13:59:27 UTC] {task_command.py:410} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: my_test_dag.task_spark_test manual__2023-08-08T13:59:24.995099+00:00 [running]> on host 11cda94a3d09
[2023-08-08, 13:59:27 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1547} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='***' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='my_test_dag' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='task_spark_test' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2023-08-08T13:59:24.995099+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2023-08-08T13:59:24.995099+00:00'
[2023-08-08, 13:59:27 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'spark_connection' for task execution.
[2023-08-08, 13:59:27 UTC] {spark_submit.py:339} INFO - Spark-Submit cmd: spark-submit --master spark://MacBook-Pro-de-Admin-9.local:7077 --name arrow-spark /opt/***/dags/sparkjob.py
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.4.1
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: test
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: default
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: default
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
[2023-08-08, 13:59:42 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:42 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: default; groups with view permissions: EMPTY; users with modify permissions: default; groups with modify permissions: EMPTY
[2023-08-08, 13:59:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:43 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 40231.
[2023-08-08, 13:59:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:43 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
[2023-08-08, 13:59:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:43 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
[2023-08-08, 13:59:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:43 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
[2023-08-08, 13:59:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:43 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
[2023-08-08, 13:59:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:43 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
[2023-08-08, 13:59:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:43 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-c1468ee3-554e-4650-851c-b520975ab0e9
[2023-08-08, 13:59:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:43 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 434.4 MiB
[2023-08-08, 13:59:43 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:43 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
[2023-08-08, 13:59:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:44 INFO JettyUtils: Start Jetty 0.0.0.0:4040 for SparkUI
[2023-08-08, 13:59:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:44 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
[2023-08-08, 13:59:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:44 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://MacBook-Pro-de-Admin-9.local:7077...
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 13:59:45 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master MacBook-Pro-de-Admin-9.local:7077
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:322)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:102)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:110)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:108)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to MacBook-Pro-de-Admin-9.local/127.0.0.1:7077
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:284)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:214)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:226)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
[2023-08-08, 13:59:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - ... 4 more
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: MacBook-Pro-de-Admin-9.local/127.0.0.1:7077
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:24 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:44 WARN StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
[2023-08-08, 14:00:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:44 ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
[2023-08-08, 14:00:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:44 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 33041.
[2023-08-08, 14:00:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:44 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 11cda94a3d09:33041
[2023-08-08, 14:00:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:44 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
[2023-08-08, 14:00:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:44 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 11cda94a3d09, 33041, None)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:44 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 11cda94a3d09:33041 with 434.4 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 11cda94a3d09, 33041, None)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:44 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 11cda94a3d09, 33041, None)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:44 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:44 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 11cda94a3d09, 33041, None)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:45 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py:317: FutureWarning: Python 3.7 support is deprecated in Spark 3.4.
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - warnings.warn("Python 3.7 support is deprecated in Spark 3.4.", FutureWarning)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:45 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext is stopping with exitCode 0.
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:45 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://11cda94a3d09:4040
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:45 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:45 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend$StandaloneDriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:45 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:45 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - File "/opt/***/dags/sparkjob.py", line 4, in <module>
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - .appName("test") \
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 480, in getOrCreate
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 525, in __init__
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1588, in __call__
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - This stopped SparkContext was created at:
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - The currently active SparkContext was created at:
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:120)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.<init>(SparkSession.scala:114)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.<init>(SparkSession.scala:107)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:45 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:45 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:45 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:45 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
[2023-08-08, 14:00:45 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:45 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
[2023-08-08, 14:00:46 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
[2023-08-08, 14:00:46 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-05611ec1-537e-4252-b7cc-64365d928710/pyspark-c1db196f-4c1c-4a6f-9f21-09fc6b931377
[2023-08-08, 14:00:46 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-cb7ca993-9543-4847-a1c9-e1f18be7c3ac
[2023-08-08, 14:00:46 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - 23/08/08 14:00:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-05611ec1-537e-4252-b7cc-64365d928710
[2023-08-08, 14:00:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1824} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit.py", line 157, in execute
    self._hook.submit(self._application)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py", line 422, in submit
    f"Cannot execute: {self._mask_cmd(spark_submit_cmd)}. Error code is: {returncode}."
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: spark-submit --master spark://MacBook-Pro-de-Admin-9.local:7077 --name arrow-spark /opt/***/dags/sparkjob.py. Error code is: 1.
[2023-08-08, 14:00:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1350} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=my_test_dag, task_id=task_spark_test, execution_date=20230808T135924, start_date=20230808T135927, end_date=20230808T140046
[2023-08-08, 14:00:46 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:109} ERROR - Failed to execute job 393 for task task_spark_test (Cannot execute: spark-submit --master spark://MacBook-Pro-de-Admin-9.local:7077 --name arrow-spark /opt/***/dags/sparkjob.py. Error code is: 1.; 1643)
[2023-08-08, 14:00:46 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-08-08, 14:00:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2653} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Test performed :

- replace spark://MacBook-Pro-de-Admin-9.local:7077 by MacBook-Pro-de-Admin-9.local:7077 in the Spark connection configuration, in Airflow
- command line execution telnet MacBook-Pro-de-Admin-9.local 7077 with the following result:

```
Trying 192.XXX.X.XX...
Connected to macbook-pro-de-admin-9.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

so network and firewall rules don't block the connection normally.

Can you help me please ?